# SmoothState.js conflicting with javascript - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using smoothState on a WordPress site, however I need to add a section of javascript to create a pop-up modal.

The javascript I currently have only works when the page is refreshed, I tried a few different methods I've seen posted on here and on stackoverflow. Anything I try either doesn't work or breaks the site.

This is my working smoothstate code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  var $page = $('#smoothstate'),
      options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 4,
        onStart: {
          duration: 150, // Duration of our animation
          render: function ($container) {
            // Add your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.addClass('is-exiting');
            // Restart your animation
            smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
          }
        },
        onReady: {
          duration: 0,
          render: function ($container, $newContent) {
            // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
            // Inject the new content
            $container.html($newContent);
    $container.addClass('fade--in');
          }
        }
      }
});
```

This is my javascript I need to load:

```
(function($) {
    $(".orange-btn").click(function(e){
        $(".hidden").fadeIn( 500 );
        $(".hidden").addClass( "click" );
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".closebox").addClass( "close" );
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I'd be really grateful if anyone could help! Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't work" - do you see any errors in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Nope, even when the page wont load it doesn't show any errors